# Threshold function does not work OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, threshold

I just want to do convert a gray image to a binary image. But threshold function gives me a totaly black image as a binary image. I want to get dark gray object.
What is wrong here?

Code:

```
Mat theFrame = imread("C:\\asdsss.png"); // opencv

Mat gray,binary;
cvtColor(theFrame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(gray, binary, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY); 
imwrite("result.jpg",binary);
```

İnput image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine. I ran you exact code on the image provided. There is no issue with it. 
[image]

I got the following output by running your code. The only problem I can think of could be loading of image. Try to see your image using cv::imshow after loading it. Also try to convert your image into jpg format and then try loading it again. You can also try compiling and running the [opencv thresholding sample](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html).